# Why isn't my WebView filling up the entire width of my screen?

Tags: android, layout, webview, android-webview

My WebView doesn't fill the entire width of my phone. I am telling to fill_parent. Not sure why?

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
    <LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:orientation="horizontal">

    <WebView android:layout_height="fill_parent" android:layout_width="fill_parent" android:id="@+id/WebView"></WebView>
    </LinearLayout>
```

Comment: You should give us the whole XML, because I can see a `LinearLayout` there...

Comment: you need to highlight any code you post in and click on the "code" button.  Otherwise it won't show up right in the question, and if its xml may get hidden entirely.

Comment: I don't see any obvious problems there.  The HeirarchyViewer might help you find the problem.  You can find it in the tools directory.

Comment: This is the whole XML. Its just a LinearLayout with a WebView

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The linear layout is orientation horizontal I don't think you can fill width on orientation horizontal.

Try using RelativeLayout instead. (just rename LinearLayout  to RelativeLayout)

Comment: if didn't solve the issue, why it's marked as the correct answer?

Answer (score 15):

That size is being taken up by the webview's scroll bar. use this to get rid of it

```
browser.setScrollBarStyle(View.SCROLLBARS_INSIDE_OVERLAY);
```

Answer (score 5):

In Activity layout (xml) and more specifically LinearLayout Tag contains some padding by default like:
    android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"

Delete that, set your WebView to fill_parent and then it will do the job.

Answer (score 0):

I know in my xml you will fill the width up with no issues... check it out.

you will see i am using the wrap_content in my base LinearLayout

```
   <LinearLayout android:orientation="horizontal"  android:background="@drawable/dailygoal"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" android:layout_width="fill_parent"
       android:padding="3px"

      >         
            <WebView
        android:id="@+id/dailygoalswebview"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
         android:layout_gravity="right"
         android:padding="20px" 
        >
    </WebView>
             </LinearLayout>
```

I just applied the above xml to my main.xml layout...  i hope you the best of luck..

Answer (score 0):

In Activity layout (xml) either it may be relative or other layout it contains some padding by default like: android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin" android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin" android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin" android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"

delete the above lines, and fill the width and height to be "fill_parent".
this works