# Android Application doesn't occupy the entire screen

Tags: android, screen, fullscreen, resolution

I am trying to run my application on a custom screen resolution but my application is centered and only occupies 320x480 (Portrait) and 480x320 (Landscape) of the screen and is horizontally aligned to the top of the activity.

While other apps and the default android activities behave aptly my application doesn't. I haven't used any fixed values or layout properties. It's just a hello world app.

[image]

I have tried themes and window features but nothing seem to work. Any pointers would be greatly appreciated. Thanks.

Comment: Refer to this question:

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6762818/my-webview-does-not-fill-the-tabs-screens-but-fills-the-cellphones-screens-wit/6767772#6767772

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Kumar Bibek](https://stackoverflow.com/users/220579/kumar-bibek) has answerd this question in a similar [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6762818/my-webview-does-not-fill-the-tabs-screens-but-fills-the-cellphones-screens-wit/6767772#6767772).

The application was running in compatibility mode for tablets. I added the following to my *AndroidManifest.xml* and it works fine.

```
<supports-screens android:largeScreens="true"
      android:normalScreens="true" android:smallScreens="true"
      android:anyDensity="true" android:xlargeScreens="false" />
```